# Pegar elemento da json com PHP

Tags: php, json

Fiz um print_r() de um resultado em json que deu o seguinte:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => 1
    [resultado] => stdClass Object
        (
            [BUSCA_BIN] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [BUSCA_BIN] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [ITEM_ID] => MVT1687

[...]
```

Gostaria de pegar o  elemento **ITEM_ID**, mas esta sempre retornando NULL.

Como estou tentando:

```
var_dump($json->resultado->BUSCA_BIN->BUSCA_BIN->ITEM_ID);

//RESULTA UM NULL.
```

O que faço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O último `BUSCA_BIN` é um [array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php), exemplo:

```
var_dump($json->resultado->BUSCA_BIN->BUSCA_BIN[0]->ITEM_ID);
```

<sub>***Referencia:*** [PHP - array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php)</sub>

Comment: eu tinha feito isso e não deu certo. Agora deu. Obrigado pela a resposta.